# Is it possible to have hot reloading inside the VS-Code Debugger with an express.js server

Tags: node.js, express, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Is it possible to have hot reloading inside the VS-Code Debugger with a running express.js server on node.JS?

That means I start the debugger as follows.
The index.ts is a simple express.js server that contains/routes API requests.

The debugging this way is working well when I start it by the VS-Code Debugger. But when I change something in my code I need to re-run the whole debugger application which takes around 30s in my case.

Is it possible to have something like a **hot reloading** here?

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "RUN EXPRESS.JS SERVER",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "trace": "all",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\index.ts",
            "preLaunchTask": "tsc: build – tsconfig.json",
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**/*.js"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to use [ts-node-dev](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node-dev) to simply the setup. This will enable realtime compiling of needed files hence reducing the restart time.

Something like [This](https://gist.github.com/cecilemuller/2963155d0f249c1544289b78a1cdd695) should work.

Comment: Thanks. I will try that. Good idea.

Comment: Have any progress?